# Linux bulk file rename/copy

Tags: linux, unix

In Linux I have a permanent directory structure which stores 5 different types of files for each month of the year going back to 2005, like so

2005/01/file1 file2 file3 file4 file5

2005/02/file1 file2 file3 file4 file5

...

2015/11/file1 file2 file3 file4 file5

2015/12/file1 file2 file3 file4 file5

I need to replace each instance of file1 from an identical temporary directory structure, except each leaf in the temporary structure only has file1 (file2/3/4/5 do not exist).  How can I do one bulk command to rename each file1 to file1.bak in the permanent structure, and then a command to copy each new file1 instance to the proper location in the permanent structure?

Comment: You can try `rename 1 1.bak 20??/??/file1`. Or you can use a for loop. `for dir in 20??/??; do mv ${dir}/file1 ${dir}/file1.bak`. As for copying to permanent directory, it's just a matter of prefixing the parent directory and using the same logic of the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this command to rename all `file1` to `file1.bak`:

```
find . -name file1 | sed -e "p;s/file1/file1.bak/" | xargs -n2 mv
```

Then copy new files `file1` with `cp -R`

Answer (score 1):

I'd first start with the multiple rename -- cd into the root directory you want to search through .. (Above `/2015/`).

```
find spec -name "*file1" -exec sh -c 'echo mv "$1" "$(echo "$1" | sed s/file1\$/bak.file1/)"' _ {} \;
```

Then simply do a mass `cp` if you are certain the file structures are the same.  Lets assume we're working with `/var/www/2015/` and `/var/www/COPY/`  and those two directories are the same structure internally ...  then simply

```
cp -R /var/www/COPY/* /var/www/2015/
```

Whatever files DON'T EXIST in `2015` that do in `COPY` will be copied FROM `/var/www/COPY/` TO `/var/www/2015/` without overwriting existing files (file2, 3 4 5 etc).

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative that may or may not be useful for you is `vidir`, which is in the `moreutils` package in Debian-family distros.

It opens your directory in your `$EDITOR` (or your system's default editor), and you can edit files in here to your heart's content. You can then just use your `$EDITOR`'s search/replace function to rename your files and save.